# Уменьшение столбца в QGridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qlayout, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

Возникла проблема при создании клавиатуры калькулятора на *PyQt5*. 
Выглядит не очень гармонично, когда столбец с одной цифрой занимает **`70px`** .

[image: Широкие колонки]

Все кнопки расположены внутри `QGridLayout`.

Как уменьшить ширину столбца, чтобы кнопки были поуже, либо вообще квадратные?

Сейчас реализую создание клавиатуры вложенным циклом:

```py
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(5):
        a = [[1, 2, 3, 'X', '÷'],
             [4, 5, 6, '-', '√'],
             [7, 8, 9, '+', 'n!'],
             ['.', 0, 'C', '=']]
        if i != 3:
            self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
            layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j)
        else:
            if j <= 2:
                self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')
                self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
                layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j)
            elif j == 3:
                self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')
                self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
                layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j, 1, 2)
```

Пробовал методы `resize()`, а также `setColumnWidth()`. 
Ничего из этого не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralwidget = QWidget()                        
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)             

        layout = QGridLayout(centralwidget)  

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(5):
                a = [[1, 2, 3, 'X', '÷'],
                     [4, 5, 6, '-', '√'],
                     [7, 8, 9, '+', 'n!'],
                     ['.', 0, 'C', '=']]
                if i != 3:
                    self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')

                    self.btn.setFixedSize(QSize(40,40))              # +

                    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
                    layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j)
                else:
                    if j <= 2:
                        self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')
                        self.btn.setFixedSize(QSize(40,40))           # +
                        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
                        layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j)
                    elif j == 3:
                        self.btn = QPushButton(f'{a[i][j]}')
                        self.btn.setFixedSize(QSize(90,40))           # +
                        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.main)
                        layout.addWidget(self.btn, i + 1, j, 1, 2)

    def main(self):
        print(self.sender().text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]